# Распарсить JSON с помощью GSON

Tags: json, vkontakte-api

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ParseWorkFlow {

     public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
     {
        String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0";  

        final String request = "https://api.vk.com/method/database.getUniversities";

        int[] CitiesToParse = {1, 2}; //массив с нужными городами

        List<String> universities = new ArrayList<>(); //массив с результатом парса(все еще в JSON)


        for(int i = 0; i < CitiesToParse.length; i++) {

            String urlString = request + "?city_id=" + (int)CitiesToParse[i] + "&count=2";

            URL url = new URL(urlString);  
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();  
            con.setRequestMethod("GET");   
            con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);  


            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
            String output;  
            StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();  

            while ((output = in.readLine()) != null) 
            {  
             response.append(output);  
            }

            in.close();  

            String strParseResult = response.toString(); 

            System.out.println(strParseResult);

            universities.add(strParseResult);


        }


     }
}
```

В конце кода для теста привел результат к строке и вывел на экран.

Код выдает следующее:

```
{"response":[713,{"id":2,"title":"МГУ"},{"id":86,"title":"АПИ при ИГиП РАН"}]}

{"response":[289,{"id":1,"title":"СПбГУ"},{"id":5,"title":"АРБ им. Вагановой"}]}
```

Есть библиотека GSON. С помощью нее хочу распарсить результат.

Вставляю в http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/, получаю один класс. (мне кажется не совсем то что нужно)

Помогите распарсить. Весь мозг сломал уже.

Comment: String urlString = request + ?country_id=1" + "&city_id=" + (int)CitiesToParse[i] + "&count=" + (int)count + "&fields=bdate" + "&v=5.60";

     После того как я добавил к запросу к API два последних параметра, стал приходить правильный JSON формат.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все, вопрос решен.
Додумался.

После правильного запроса к vk api, получаем правильный JSON, парсим его GSON и все.

Далее буду обращаться к элементам каждого спарсенного унивеситета по id в цикле для получения списка факультетов и кафедр.